# 64 bit iphone: jquery not working

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

my phonegap application runs on the regular iphone retina perfectly, but if i run the 64 bit simulator it will succeed but none of the jquery mobile code is working. Is there any quick fix for this? It's jquery mobile 1.3.2, and phonegap 2.9 i believe

Thanks

Comment: "Quick fix" for what? A small, self-contained example of something that's not working would help.

Comment: well none of the js is working on the 64bit but it works on the old iphone so clearly its not a code thing.